# allow port for some IPs IPTABLES

Tags: centos, firewall, iptables

On CentOS 7 i Use following commands to drop some port and allow for one IP :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2001 -s 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2001 -j DROP
service iptables save
```

and everything work fine.
But when i want add another ip to allow with this command it doesn't work for second IP.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2001 -s 2.2.2.2 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

Answer (score 0):

** Solved **

I use `-I` Flag This would insert your rule on first position of inputs rule.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 2001 -s 2.2.2.2 -j ACCEPT
```